# window.mozIndexedDB is null in Firefox 15

Tags: html, firefox, indexeddb

I'm trying to run the "Using IndexedDB" sample code on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB

Right out of the gate I stumble with the first line of code:
`window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;`

Using Firebug I see that `window.indexedDB` is undefined as expected for FF 15, window.webkitIndexedDB is undefined as expected (FF isn't webkit) but `window.mozIndexedDB` is null but not undefined. If it's null that tells me it exists but doesn't have a valid value/isn't initialized.

This is with Firefox 15.0.1 on OSX 10.6.8 and Ubuntu 12.04. Can somebody tell me why I'm not able to see/use `window.mozIndexedDB`? Am I doing something wrong?

For completeness, here's my JavaScript file:

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;

var request = window.indexedDB.open("MyTestDatabase", 3);
var db;

request.onerror = function (event) {
    alert("Oops, request.onerror");
};

request.onsuccess = function (event) {
    // Do something with request.result!
    alert("Made it to request.onsuccess");

    db = request.result;
};

// This event is only implemented in recent browsers
request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
    alert("Made it to request.onupgradeneeded");
};

db.onerror = function (event) {
    alert("Database error (db.onerror): " + event.target.errorCode);
};
```

Comment: `window.mozIndexedDB` shouldn't be null in Firefox 15. Are you using some special version of Firefox, or the normal one from the Ubuntu repos?

Comment: I used both the Firefox from the Ubuntu repos and did an install directly from Mozilla.

Comment: are you running this code inside an iframe?

Comment: No, I was running it directly from the file system. Running it from Apache httpd works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original HTML5 application uses jQuery Mobile & REST WS. In development I would run it directly from the file system and it works fine. For sharing with coworkers I have it running behind Apache httpd.

While adding the IndexedDB, I was trying to test by viewing files from the file system via the browser. It didn't work and that's what caused me to go back to square one and try running the example code from Mozilla.

It appears IndexedDB requires a domain even if it's localhost. I simply placed my code under public_html and viewed it via httpd/localhost and it's working perfectly.

Comment: I believe the problem is caused because you need to run inside a domain (origin).