# window.mozindexdb is null in Firefox 14 to 16 version

Tags: jquery, html

I am opening files without HTTP protocol in Firefox versions 14-16.

I am unable open the `indexdb`. My syntax is this:

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
var IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction;
var request = window.indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
    alert('Success')
};
```

With Firebug I am able to see `window.mozIndexedDB` is `null`.

In localhost it is working fine, But I need to run without HTTP.

Are any changes are needed to my code?

Comment: This answer will probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770991/window-mozindexeddb-is-null-in-firefox-15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of stuff is disabled on the file protocol for "security" seasons. I tried to find the reason on the Mozilla site, but they do not mention it on MDN anywhere about the restriction. BUT if you go to the dark side, Microsoft mentions the restriction.

From [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779017%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Note  The following code examples require a browser that supports File
>   API and Indexed Database API, such as Internet Explorer 10 or later.
>   Additionally, each example has an associated "Live link", which links
>   to a working code sample (using the http protocol). For security
>   reasons, Indexed Database API only works through the http, https,
>   ms-wwa, or ms-wwa-web protocols in Windows Internet Explorer. That is,
>   **Internet Explorer doesn't allow a local HTML page ( file://) to fully
>   execute the Indexed Database API.** Instead, the page must be behind a
>   supported protocol such as http:// or https://. If convenient, a local
>   web server can be used to preview IndexedDB pages using the loopback
>   address (127.0.0.1).